# Can we represent a graph using binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, graph

I am currently doing some graph data structures problem and i did encounter with adjacency matrix and list to represent a graph in computers memory, but this thing clicked on my mind if we can use BST to store the edges of the graph, then insertion and searching both can be done in log n time, can any one give me any clarification whether we can do it that way or not ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Can we represent a graph in BST?**

Depends on what you call a graph. BST is also a graph. But, when you're talking about graphs as a whole, you cannot represent it using BST. Why?

1. A node in BST will have only two children where a node in a graph can be connected to any number of nodes. Adjacency matrix can represent this connectivity by having a row for each node and representing its connectivity status with each other node.
2. Trees can only represent the hierarchical structure, wherein a graph, connectivity need not be hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit misleading. I think you want to say:

> If the edges are stored in a **set** one can do fast (log n) set operations for addition/deletion.

Indeed in software sometimes a Vertex object holds a set of naybors, or Edges.

It is a matter of space-time choices. An adjacency matrix (if it is not too sparse, many vertices, few edges) is both compact and regular, say for vector operations or student solutions.